# What do you call the technique of integrating type into an image / background with perspective?

Tags: typography, images, style-identification

I'm having a really hard time describing this: 
[image: GTA IV TITLE]

It's from the [GTA IV Title / Intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo_9uifCivI). I'm talking about the way the text is part of the image in regards to perspective. Some even go so far as to have some elements of the picture appear to be in front of the text etc. - can't show an example because I'm having such a hard time googling it :(

Comment: Welcome along, a well written question with good examples :-D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would refer to this as **"motion tracking text"** or **"3D tracking text"** - a search for these terms returns many, MANY tutorials etc.